# V-for in 1 line with something in between

Tags: vue.js, inline, v-for

I am trying to display an array with v-for in 1 line which is working but I want to add "," in between every word. The only problem is when I do this it will end with an "," too. Any suggestions?

Comment: show a template code

Comment: Consider making a computed property where you [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the comma-separated list in JS instead of in the template.

Answer (score 2):

[`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) joins strings with the specified *"glue"* (`comma` + `space` in this case):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ 
    items: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
  }),
  computed: {
    displayItems() {
      return this.items.join(', ');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Items: {{ displayItems }}
</div>
```

One could even argue that, given it's a very simple case, you shouldn't bother with a `computed`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ 
    items: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Items: {{ items.join(', ') }}
</div>
```

If you really want to use tags, you can solve the problem using CSS pseudo elements:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ 
    items: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
  })
})
```

```css
#app > span:after {
  content: ', '
}
#app > span:last-child:after {
  content: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Items: <span v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key" v-text="item"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Better approach but without using the `v-for`

Comment: @dvilla, I added a solution for `v-for`, too. However, if the only purpose of those tags is to iterate through the array, I'd strongly advise against using tags. One of the first rules of performance is: keep your number of DOM elements as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the comma inside a `<template>` and check if that is the last item

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="(item, index) of items" :key="i">
      {{item}}<template v-if="index !== items.length - 1">,</template>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: ['test A', 'test B', 'test C']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```